# Invalid plugin specification. Invalid "macos" plugin specification

Tags: flutter

Hi I am getting the following error when I run `flutter build ios`

> Invalid plugin specification. Invalid "macos" plugin specification.

Any ideas?

**Flutter Doctor**

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel unknown, v1.12.0, on Mac OS X 10.13.6 17G66)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.3)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 10.2.1)
[✓] Android Studio (version 3.6)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found that reinstalling every tool you are using and then re-installing the stable version of each tool has helped other people, as found here: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/52322

Hope it helps!